# selector for selecting only checked items in list in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery multiselect plugin

I have some item disabled and some item checked in the list

I want to extract only text of checked item

my code is

```
var cval2 = $('#lsltrXYAxis option:checked').not(":disabled").map(function () {
            return this.value.replace('ltrXYAxis', '');
        }).get().join('@@');
```

HTML of disabled item is

```
<label class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" title="" for="ui-multiselect-lsltrXYAxis-option-0">
<input id="ui-multiselect-lsltrXYAxis-option-0" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled" title="" value="ltrXYAxisApple Identifier" name="multiselect_lsltrXYAxis">
<span>Apple Identifier</span>
</label>
```

and HTML of checked Item is

```
<label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-lsltrXYAxis-option-1">
<input id="ui-multiselect-lsltrXYAxis-option-1" type="checkbox" aria-selected="true" checked="checked" title="" value="ltrXYAxisCustomer Price" name="multiselect_lsltrXYAxis">
<span>Customer Price</span>
</label>
```

But it also returns me disbaled item added with @@

Whats wrong with selector
Any Help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing below

```
 var cval2 = $(':#lsltrXYAxis option:selected:not(:disabled)').map(function () {
                return this.value.replace('ltrXYAxis', '');
            }).get().join('@@');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mistakenly using `option` tag selector while in your HTML you have `input`.

Try this:

```
$('#lsltrXYAxis input:checked:not(:disabled)');
```

Also, if you need to associate some data with your elements, you better use the `data` attribute instead of extracting and replacing data from the `value` attribute.

Instead of:

```
<input value="ltrXYAxisCustomer Price" ... />
```

Try:

```
<input data-val="Price" ... />
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
return $(this).data('val');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `:checked` selector.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) of the `:selected` selector specifies, that "The `:selected` selector works for `<option>` elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio `inputs`; use `:checked` for them."

Comment: Please have a look at haim770's answer